# Scroll up command history in Vim without using function key

Tags: keyboard, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently bought HHKB (Happy Hacking KeyBoard), and it doesn't have direction keys -- it's through `Fn + ;'[/` to achieve direction key.

Therefore, I'm trying to avoid using direction key as much as possible. One occasion when I'll have to use direction key is.. in vim, to browse up the command history, here's how I used it:

1. say I'm writing a Ruby program, then I just use `:!ruby %` to run it directly.
2. then later on I want to run this ruby program again, then usually how I do with a direction key is: `:<up>`

Now I don't have direction key, and I think it is too troublesome to press `Fn + [` to simulate the direction key. Is there a way I can achieve that without direction key?

Thanks

Comment: I would go with Thomas answer for your question. But for you example it could be better to have a simple mapping and possible use a plugin such as [SingleCompile](https://github.com/xuhdev/SingleCompile) to run and display/update the results on a separated window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to scroll forward/backward through the history.

Comment: Hmm what if I want to scroll wit filter? Like.. if I type `!` then `<up>`, it would actually give me all the history with leading `!`. <ctrl>+<p> cannot do filter.

Comment: BTW, how did u show the it as keyboard key?

Comment: If I type `!`, then control+p, vim scrolls through history without apparent difference versus a cursor-key.  If you find some new issue not in your original question, you should provide a new question.

Comment: Try this: 1) go to vim, type `:!date`; 2) type `:w`; 3) type `:!`, then try to scroll up in history. If u use `<up>` key, then it would show you `:!date`; while if u use `<ctrl>-p`, then it would show u `:w`. That is the difference I meant